# Somewhere, something, somebody & someone referring to multiple things

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I read the usage of "somewhere, something, somebody & someone" on Cambridge and it says that those words can be used to describe general **people & things**. But all the example they give uses singular verb (i.e. verbs with s/es). Can those 4 words be used to refer to many unknown/general things, such as in this sentence:

> The ghost costume looks like something from a horror movie.

Comment: What are the "multiple things" in your example? (All the nouns you've used there are singular.)

Comment: Please add a link so that we can examine 'Cambridge''s exact words. It's probably just 'A uses 'somewhere' to refer to one unnamed (or unknown or even imaginary) place (perhaps in Africa), while B uses it to refer to another (perhaps in the Arctic). Unnamed place**s**.

Answer (score 1):

You have not fully understood what the dictionary is saying.

“I saw you **somewhere** in France.”

**Somewhere** is a singular noun and an adverb:

“I saw you **somewhere** (adv.) in France.” = **at** an unknown/unspecified place.

“The ship has come from **somewhere** (n.) and is going to **somewhere**(n.) = an unknown/unspecified place.

The plural of “**somewhere**(n.)” is “**some places**”. **- two words**
 
“The ship has come from some places in Africa.”

“The battles were fought at some places in France.”

**Something** is a singular noun:

“Something(n.) is making a noise.” / “I need something(n.) to write with.” = an unknown/unspecified thing /object.

The plural of “**something** (n.) is “**some things**” – **two words**

“I will put some things into the attic.”

**Somebody** and **someone** are nouns:

“**Somebody(n.) / Someone(n.)** is making a noise.” / “I need somebody(n.)/ someone(n.) to help me.” = an unknown/unspecified person.

The plural of “**somebody (n.) / someone(n.)** is “some people” – two words

“**Some people** are making a noise.” / “I need **some people** to help me.”

Comment: Some of those actually can be turned into plurals in the right context: *There were two twenty-**somethings** walking down the street.* In fact, we would write it that way; we would not use *twenty-**some things**.* Or: *Don't give me all the **somewheres** and **wherefores**, just tell me what you mean.* But those are unusual uses of the words, treating them as countable nouns.

Comment: Is "The ghost costume**s** look like something from a horror movie" acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it is. "... like something from ..." ≈ "like a group of items from". The plural (some things) would be wrong in this context, as "something" treats "all the ghost costumes" as one set/group. ++ If you want to avoid this: ""The ghost costumes look as if they came from a horror movie".